# Import all rows from dataset using SODA API Python

Tags: python, json, soda

I'm trying to import the following dataset and store it in a pandas dataframe: https://data.nasa.gov/Space-Science/Meteorite-Landings/gh4g-9sfh/data

I use the following code:

```
 r = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json')
 meteor_data = r.json()
 df = pd.DataFrame(meteor_data)
 print(df.shape)
```

The resulting dataframe only has 1000 rows. I need it to have all 45,716 rows. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs on the $limit parameter](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/)

> The $limit parameter controls the total number of rows returned, and
>   it defaults to 1,000 records per request.
>
> **Note**: The maximum value for $limit is 50,000 records, and if you
>   exceed that limit you'll get a 400 Bad Request response.

So you're just getting the default number of records back.

You will not be able to get more than 50,000 records in a single API call - this will take multiple calls using $limit together with $offset

Try:

```
https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json$limit=50000
```

See [Why am I limited to 1,000 rows on SODA API when I have an App Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941170/why-am-i-limited-to-1-000-rows-on-soda-api-when-i-have-an-app-key)

Answer (score 0):

**DO LIKE This ans set limit**

```
import pandas as pd
from sodapy import Socrata

# Unauthenticated client only works with public data sets. Note 'None'
# in place of application token, and no username or password:
client = Socrata("data.nasa.gov", None)

# Example authenticated client (needed for non-public datasets):
# client = Socrata(data.nasa.gov,
#                  MyAppToken,
#                  userame="user@example.com",
#                  password="AFakePassword")

# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
results = client.get("gh4g-9sfh", limit=2000)

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I know now this question was asked a long time ago but I am replying here so that some other user may get benefitted.
I am modifying the code of @Rachit Kumar a little by setting the limit as a very large absurd number to download all the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from sodapy import Socrata

# Unauthenticated client only works with public data sets. Note 'None'
# in place of application token, and no username or password:
client = Socrata("data.nasa.gov", None)

# Example authenticated client (needed for non-public datasets):
# client = Socrata(data.nasa.gov,
#                  MyAppToken,
#                  userame="user@example.com",
#                  password="AFakePassword")

# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
results = client.get("gh4g-9sfh", limit=999999)

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
results_df
```

Please note that the limit is set to any large number